# Binomial expansion extension to negative powers

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I know that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}a^{n-k}b^k = (a+b)^n$$

But how is this extended to negative powers, for example, I came across the following line of maths, which I struggle to understand:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}{2r \choose r}x^r = (1-4x)^{-1/2}$$

as well as the following:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} (2r+1){2r \choose r}x^r = (1-4x)^{-3/2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples are *[binomial series expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* 
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^{\alpha}=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{r}x^r\qquad\qquad  |x|<1  \tag{1}
\end{align*}
convergent for $|x|<1$ with the following definition of binomial coefficients
\begin{align*}
\binom{\alpha}{r}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)\cdots(\alpha-r+1)}{r!}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> (1-4x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}&=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{r}(-4x)^r\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^r}{4^r}\binom{2r}{r}(-4x)^r\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}x^r
> \end{align*}
>   and similarly
>   \begin{align*}
> (1-4x)^{-\frac{3}{2}}&=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{-\frac{3}{2}}{r}(-4x)^r\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^r}{4^r}(2r+1)\binom{2r}{r}(-4x)^r\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}(2r+1)\binom{2r}{r}x^r
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we use according to (2)
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{r}&=\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}-1\right)\left(-\frac{1}{2}-3\right)\cdots\left(-\frac{1}{2}-r+1\right)}{r!}\\
  &=\frac{(-1)^r}{2^r}\cdot\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2r-1)}{r!}\\
  &=\frac{(-1)^r}{2^r}\cdot\frac{(2r-1)!!}{r!}\\
  &=\frac{(-1)^r}{2^r}\cdot\frac{(2r)!}{(2r)!!r!}\\
  &=\frac{(-1)^r}{4^r}\cdot\frac{(2r)!}{r!r!}\\
  &=\frac{(-1)^r}{4^r}\binom{2r}{r}\\
  \end{align*}
  It is convenient to use *[double factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)* and the formulas $$(2r)!=(2r)!!(2r-1)!!\qquad\text{ and }\qquad(2r)!!=2^rr!$$
- In (4) we find similarly to (3)
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-\frac{3}{2}}{r}=\frac{(-1)^r}{4^r}(2r+1)\binom{2r}{r}
  \end{align*}

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you very much

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: You're welcome! :-)

Comment: Is it fair to say the following: $(1+x)^a = \sum_{k=0}^a {a \choose k} x^k \ \ \ \forall a > 0$ and $(1+x)^a = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {a \choose k} x^k \ \ \ \forall a < 0$

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: This is not quite correct, since e.g. $\sqrt{1+x}=(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{k}x^k$. It's convenient to set $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k>n$. So, we can *always* set $(1+x)^a=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{a}{k}x^k$. You can even extend $a$ to $\mathbb{C}$. See the ref of binomial expansion. Regards,

Comment: also, in the comment, when you give an expression for ${1/2 \choose r}$, in the numerator it should be: $(-1/2-2)$, just a small typo

Comment: Ok, so I can only say $(1+x)^a = \sum_{k=0}^a {a \choose k} x^k \ \ \ \forall a > 0$ if $a \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: Correct.